# Trying to create a trigger that tracks users changes they make on a table but keep getting error ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER placement_audit_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON LDS_PLACEMENT
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
v_user varchar(30);
v_date varchar(30);
BEGIN
SELECT user, TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_user, v_date FROM dual;
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES(:NEW.PLACEMENT_ID, NULL, v_user, v_date, 'Insert');
ELSIF DELETING THEN 
INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUE (NULL,:OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');
ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES(:NEW.PLACEMENT_ID, :OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, v_user, v_date,'Update');
END IF; 
END;
```

Trying to create a trigger, to track changes in table that a user makes but keep ORA-24344: success with compilation error i have researched and tried to resolve the issues could anyone give me an idea where i'm going wrong or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please, type "show errors;" under trigger user after receiving error (if you're using SQLPlus command line) or select from user_errors view to get more detailed message.

Comment: Why on earth do you store and insert the sysdate as VARCHAR2?

Comment: You can simply write the inserts like `INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES(:NEW.PLACEMENT_ID, :OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, USER, SYSDATE,'Update');` - there is not need for `select ... into ... from dual;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit how do I define the user that makes the changes please read the question

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is right - change v_date varchar(30) to v_date date.

Comment: if you run this in sql developer, we'll show you the errors. otherwise, do what @dimitry-yankin says, add a 'show errors' to the end of your script

Comment: `value` should be `values`. What tool are you using for your PL/SQL development?

Comment: You don't need to select anything from dual as you can just refer to `user`, `sysdate` etc directly in your `insert` statement. However I can't see the point of recording the trigger's schema in an audit table, as it will always be the same. It would make more sense to capture `sys_context('userenv','session_user'))` or `sys_context('userenv','os_user'))`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, function `USER` returns the current user name, not the current schema (`sys_context('userenv','CURRENT_USER`)` would return the triggers's schema, provided it is defined as "definer's rights")

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are quite right, `user` is the invoking user and so it is reasonable to capture it for an audit trail. I was mixing it up with current_user.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it must be

```
INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUES (NULL,:OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
VALUE (NULL,:OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, v_user, v_date, 'Delete');
```

`VALUES` instead of `VALUE`

As mentioned in comment there is no need for `select ... into ... from dual`, so just write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER placement_audit_trigger 
   BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON LDS_PLACEMENT
   FOR EACH ROW
   ENABLE

BEGIN

   IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
      VALUES (:NEW.PLACEMENT_ID, NULL, USER, SYSDATE, 'Insert');
   ELSIF DELETING THEN 
      INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
      VALUES (NULL,:OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, USER, SYSDATE, 'Delete');
   ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
      INSERT INTO placement_audit (new_name, old_name, user_name, entry_date, operation)
      VALUES (:NEW.PLACEMENT_ID, :OLD.PLACEMENT_ID, USER, SYSDATE,'Update');
   END IF; 
END;
```